# Unable to establish connection to http://controller:35357/v3/auth/tokens

Tags: openstack

Hi StackOverflow Members:

Here is one problem when I tries to install the openstack images in the following link step:

```
http://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/install-guide-ubuntu/glance-install.html
```

when I tries to type the following commands:

```
openstack user create --domain default --password-prompt glance
```

it shows the following errors:

```
Discovering versions from the identity service failed when creating the       
password plugin. Attempting to determine version from URL. Unable to   
establish connection to http://controller:35357/v3/auth/tokens
```

I am not quite sure this problem is related to identity service.Image service is the first one for installation.How Can I fixed this installation problem?

Comment: Does the DNS name "controller" resolve?  Can you "ping" the controller system?  Can you open a TCP/IP connection to it on port 35357?

Comment: After configure the network by adding network/gateway information in /etc/network/interfaces and enable it. and checking the connection to controller(10.0.0.11). It can correctly ping well. But when I re-run the command, it shows `An unexpected error prevented the server from fulfilling your request. (HTTP 500) (Request-ID): req-4550f994-648e-4aa4-a0e9-633c27ccd212` I do not know what's wrong with that ?

Comment: Look in the logs.

Comment: Can you show me where I can find the log files about this errors ? Is it in /etc/keystone/keystone.log or ?

Comment: They will be in "/var/log/keystone/...".  You can adjust the logging configs (e.g. levels) in the config files in "/etc/keystone".  Check the Openstack documentation for details.

Comment: after studying about the python documentation and `/etc/keystone/keystone.log and logging.conf`. I tried to configure all the levels to `NOTSET` in `logging.conf`, reboot the OS and rerun the above commands. It still shows the same results. I didn't know why ?